# Insert Query is working sometimes in powershell

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm inserting some data in SQL db with help of powershell, but sometimes it works sometimes not.

My Code:

```
    $name= "TestTable"
    $Database= "Testdb"
    $date=Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    $ComputerNameValue=$env:computername
    $InsertQuery="INSERT INTO [$($Database)].[dbo].[$($name)]
               ([Date],[HostName])
         VALUES('$date','$ComputerNameValue')
    "
```

After SQL connection my code

```
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand  
$SqlCmd.Connection = $conn  
$SqlCmd.CommandText = $InsertQuery  
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter  
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd   
#Creating Dataset  
$Datatable = New-Object "System.Data.Datatable"
$result = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery() 
$conn.Close()
```

But in db sometimes its not working as shown in image.
[image: db image]

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: So, in the cases where the hostname end up blank in the database, what's the actual value of `$env:ComputerName`?

Comment: Why dont you use 

invoke-sqlcmd -username username -password Password -query $QUERY -serverinstance $instance -database "DB" -connectiontimeout 180 -QueryTimeOut 300 -DisableVariables

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, thanks for reply, in log i can see all values in place, but in database sometimes it becomes blank

Comment: @DheerajMutha, thanks for reply, the above script runs in multiple systems. To use invoke-cmd i have to install module, but i don't have rights to install in most of them. so i can't use them.

Comment: You dont need to install the module on all the systems. You only need to have the module on the source machine.